# What is the correct way to split an aurelia app into on-demand bundles using webpack?

Tags: webpack, aurelia

My app is separated into different modules, for example: src/boot/**/*.js, src/core/**/*.js, src/some-other-module/**/*.js and the same dirs in components dir.

How can I bundle my app into on-demand bundles using webpack? I want to have such modules: boot, core, some-other-module; and I want to load them on demand. For example, the very first page - the login page - should only load *boot* bundle and after successful login *core* bundle should be loaded.

I have tried this webpack.config.js:

```
// bundles.js
const glob = require('glob');
module.exports = {
  fw: ['aurelia-bootstrapper'],
  boot: [
    ...glob.sync('src/*.js').map(entry => entry.replace('src/', '')),
    ...glob.sync('src/boot/**/*.js').map(entry => entry.replace('src/', '')),
    ...glob.sync('components/boot/**/*.js').map(entry => entry.replace('components/', ''))
  ],
  core: [
    ...glob.sync('src/core/**/*.js').map(entry => entry.replace('src/', '')),
    ...glob.sync('components/core/**/*.js').map(entry => entry.replace('components/', ''))
  ],
  'some-other-module': [
    ...glob.sync('src/some-other-module/**/*.js').map(entry => entry.replace('src/', '')),
    ...glob.sync('components/some-other-module/**/*.js').map(entry => entry.replace('components/', ''))
  ],
};

// webpack.config.js
const prodBundles = require('./bundles.js');
...
module.exports = ({ production, server, extractCss, coverage } = {}) => ({
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    modules: [srcDir, componentsDir, 'node_modules', 'libs']
  },
  entry: prodBundles,
...
});
```

But app is not even working with this setup throwing such error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Error invoking Compose. Check the inner error for details.
------------------------------------------------
Inner Error:
Message: Constructor Parameter with index 0 cannot be null or undefined. Are you trying to inject/register something that doesn't exist with DI?
Inner Error Stack:
Error: Constructor Parameter with index 0 cannot be null or undefined. Are you trying to inject/register something that doesn't exist with DI?
    at Object.invokeWithDynamicDependencies (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:35219:13)
    at InvocationHandler.invoke (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:35204:166)
    at Container.invoke (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:35475:23)
    at ProviderResolver.get (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:31046:72)
    at Container.get (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:35414:21)
    at Container.elementContainerGet [as get] (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:31101:15)
    at HtmlBehaviorResource.create (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:33088:56)
    at applyInstructions (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:31203:31)
    at ViewFactory.create (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:31424:7)
    at BoundViewFactory.create (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:31304:33)
    at If._show (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:36666:36)
    at If.bind (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:73912:12)
    at Controller.bind (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:32473:22)
    at View.bind (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:30462:22)
    at Controller.bind (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:32465:17)
    at Controller.automate (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:32410:10)
End Inner Error Stack
------------------------------------------------

    at new AggregateError (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:8478:11)
    at Container.invoke (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:35477:13)
    at ProviderResolver.get (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:31046:72)
    at Container.get (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:35414:21)
    at Container.elementContainerGet [as get] (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:31101:15)
    at HtmlBehaviorResource.create (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:33088:56)
    at applyInstructions (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:31203:31)
    at ViewFactory.create (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:31424:7)
    at BoundViewFactory.create (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:31304:33)
    at If._show (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:36666:36)
    at If.bind (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:73912:12)
    at Controller.bind (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:32473:22)
    at View.bind (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:30462:22)
    at Controller.bind (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:32465:17)
    at Controller.automate (http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:32410:10)
    at http://localhost:9000/common.595063c809425d78a6ec.bundle.js:33554:18
```

So, now I even can't separate my app into bundles without on-demand loading.

Also it may be important to note that I use sass-loader.

P.S. I have read the official aurelia documentation, but it looks like outdated.

Comment: I know you said "This error is not exactly what I want to discuss." but it sort of dominates the question. Out of curiosity, why are you renaming the module specifiers produced by the globs?

Comment: @AluanHaddad, My config does not use on-demand tech, that's why I think this error is not very important. As for globs, there is resolve.modules defined as './src' and './components', therefore I need to replace this strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer here: https://ilikekillnerds.com/2017/03/code-splitting-aurelia-webpack-applications/

The main idea is that PLATFORM.moduleName takes two arguments: moduleId and chunkName. When chunkName is specified Aurelia informs webpack to create chunk which then will be loaded on demand.

Comment: I tried this in `main.js` where I set `setRoot` to different places based on if the user is logged in or not.  So, if not logged in, I do `setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('login/login','boot')` if they are logged in, `setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('app','core')`.  However, in `login.ts` once the user "logs in", I do `setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('app','core')`.  When I try to run my app, webpack hurls stating something about Cyclic Dependencies. Is it possible to do this?